# how does '\maketitle' work?

Tags: documentclass-writing, latex-base

I would like to know how the `\maketitle` command works since I am creating my own class and I want to use my own commands.
For example, I already create certain commands like `\a`, `\b` and `\c` and I want that with a certain command we say `\printabc` a new page is created printing such commands.

Thanks in advance

EDIT 1: I try to define

```
\def\@mycover{%
    \newpage\null
}
```

but get the error

> ! Use of \@ doesn't match its definition.

EDIT 2: I have made progress.

```
\documentclass{myclass}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\mytitle}[1]{\gdef\@mytitle{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}
\newcommand*{\myauthors}[5]{\gdef\@myauthors{
    \begin{tabular}{c}
        \MakeUppercase{#1} \\ 
        \MakeUppercase{#2} \\  
        \MakeUppercase{#3} \\
        \MakeUppercase{#4} \\
        \MakeUppercase{#5}
    \end{tabular}
}}
\newcommand*{\myafil}[5]{\gdef\@myafil{
    \begin{tabular}{c}
        \MakeUppercase{#1} \\ 
        \MakeUppercase{#2} \\  
        \MakeUppercase{#3} \\
        \MakeUppercase{#4} \\
        \MakeUppercase{#5}
    \end{tabular}
}}
\newcommand\makecover{\begin{titlepage}%
    \thispagestyle{empty}\centering\bfseries
    \@mytitle
    \vfill
    \@myauthors
    \vfill
    \@myafil
\end{titlepage}
\global\let\makecover\relax
\global\let\@mytitle\@empty
\global\let\@myauthors\@empty
\global\let\@myafil\@empty
\global\let\mytitle\relax
\global\let\myauthors\relax
\global\let\myafil\relax
}
\makeatother

\mytitle{The Title}
\myauthors{Author 1}{}{}{}{}
\myafil{University}{Faculty of exact and natural sciences}{Department of Mathematics}{City}{Year}

\begin{document}
\makecover
\end{document}
```

This is all right, but when I comment for example

> %\myauthors{Author 1}{}{}{}{}

the following error arises

> ! Undefined control
>   sequence.

something that does not happen in class book. why does that happen?

Comment: Basically, for example, the `\author` command does `\gdef\@author{<Something>}`, then `\maketitle` contains `\@author`, which will print `<Something>`. I suggest looking at LaTeX's base classes for some guidance: https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls?view=co

Comment: To use commands with `@` in their name you have to say `\makeatletter` before. See [What do \makeatletter and \makeatother do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/134574)

Comment: Thanks, so the command `\newcommand*{\mytitle}[1]{\gdef\@mytitle{#1}}` needs  `\makeatletter`?

Comment: Not _inside_ the  `\newcommand`, but before it. But if you are writing a class in a `.cls` file the `\makeatletter` thingy should already be active. If you are testing outside the `.cls` file then yes, you need the `\makeatletter`.

Comment: Shure, `\makeatletter\newcommand...\makeatother`. Thanks, i will try it

Comment: In the `book.cls` file, I see that they define two commands, namely, `\maketitle` and `\@maketitle`, so, why its that? what is the diference?

Comment: The `\maketitle` command is what the user will use. The `\@maketitle` is an implementation detail. It could be called (non intuitively) `\@potato` :P But in this case, the `\@maketitle` holds the actual formatting of the title and is called differently by `\maketitle` in case the `twocolumn` option is used.

Comment: It's a _really_ bad idea to edit your question to include another one. I suggest you ask a new question instead. But the error you get is because if you don't call the `\myauthors` command then the `\@myauthors` macro will never be defined, then TeX will complain that is is `Undefined`. You can add `\def\@myauthors{}` in your class file so you are sure that the macro exists. Or you can use the same approach as LaTeX and do `\def\@myauthors{\@latex@warning@no@line{No \noexpand\myauthor given}}`. *Off-topic:* I would go for a comma separated list of authors instead of `{}{}{}{}{}`...

Comment: Thanks for the first advice. So, `\def\@myauthors{\@latex@warning@no@line{No \noexpand\myauthor given}}\newcommand*{\mytitle}[1]{\gdef\@mytitle{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}` is the correct form? and... how do I make the command understand that the arguments are the entries separated by commas?

Comment: By saying `\def\@myauthors{\@latex@warning@no@line{No \noexpand\myauthor given}}` you tell LaTeX to raise a (comprehensible) error if the user of the class doesn't provide an author. Alternatively you can use `\def\@myauthors{}` then, if the author doesn't use `\myauthors`, an empty string will be used. As for the comma thing, it's _way_ more complicated than just using a `\newcommand`. [New Question ;)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)

Comment: jeje, thanks again. I create a new post https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/453007/command-with-arguments-separated-by-comma

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's assume you're basing your document class on the `article` document class. The following definition of `\maketitle` applies *if* the `titlepage` document class option was *not* set:

```
\newcommand\maketitle{\par
  \begingroup
    \renewcommand\thefootnote{\@fnsymbol\c@footnote}%
    \def\@makefnmark{\rlap{\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}}%
    \long\def\@makefntext##1{\parindent 1em\noindent
            \hb@xt@1.8em{%
                \hss\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}##1}%
    \if@twocolumn
      \ifnum \col@number=\@ne
        \@maketitle
      \else
        \twocolumn[\@maketitle]%
      \fi
    \else
      \newpage
      \global\@topnum\z@   % Prevents figures from going at top of page.
      \@maketitle
    \fi
    \thispagestyle{plain}\@thanks
  \endgroup
  \setcounter{footnote}{0}%
  \global\let\thanks\relax
  \global\let\maketitle\relax
  \global\let\@maketitle\relax
  \global\let\@thanks\@empty
  \global\let\@author\@empty
  \global\let\@date\@empty
  \global\let\@title\@empty
  \global\let\title\relax
  \global\let\author\relax
  \global\let\date\relax
  \global\let\and\relax
}
```

What's going on? The macro consists mainly of two parts.

- In the first part, i.e., the material that's sandwiched between `\begingroup` and `\endgroup`, we begin by resetting how footnotes are typeset; mostly, symbolic markers (asterisks, daggers, etc) are used as footnote markers instead of numerals. Next, LaTeX checks if the `twocolumn` document class was set; if the answer is "no", the `\newpage` instruction is executed, followed by `\@maketitle`. (The contents of `\@maketitle` are examined in more detail below.)
- In the second part, the `footnote` counter is (re)set to 0, and then the macros `\thanks`, `\maketitle`, `\@maketitle`, `\@thanks`, `\@author`, `\@date`, `\@title`, `\title`, `\author`, `\date`, and `\and` -- which are all defined in the LaTeX kernel -- are all unset. The `\global` qualifiers are needed, as otherswise the `\let\xyz\relax` directives would not apply outside of the current group, which was started by the `\begingroup` directive mentioned above.

The upshot: The macros `\title`, `\author`, `\date` can not be used again once `\maketitle` has been run. What's the purpose of unsetting these macros, you may ask? If nothing else, this step makes sure that one cannot -- accidentally or intentionally -- run `\maketitle` more than once in a document.

Finally, how is the macro `\@maketitle` defined? In `article.cls`, one finds the following code:

```
\def\@maketitle{%
  \newpage
  \null
  \vskip 2em%
  \begin{center}%
  \let \footnote \thanks
    {\LARGE \@title \par}%
    \vskip 1.5em%
    {\large
      \lineskip .5em%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
        \@author
      \end{tabular}\par}%
    \vskip 1em%
    {\large \@date}%
  \end{center}%
  \par
  \vskip 1.5em}
```

The bulk of the code occurs between `\begin{center}` and `\end{center}`: The argument of `\title`, which gets typeset via `\@title`, is set at the `\LARGE` font size (72.7% larger than `\normalsize`); the argument of `\author` gets typeset inside a 1-column `tabular` environment, in `\large` (20% larger than `\normalsize`); and the argument of `\date` (if any) also gets typeset in `\large`.  The `center` environment ends and a vertical skip of 1.5em is inserted. Importantly, no page break is inserted. Thus, if the next document element is the `abstract` environment, LaTeX will try to fit the abstract on the page that already contains the title, author, and date elements.

Comment: Is it possible to remove the `vskip 2em` parameter?

Comment: @ifly6 - Certainly. Actually, what's really needed is to remove the `\null` instruction that precedes `\vskip 2em`. To do this, I suggest you load the `etoolbox` package and run the following instructions in the preamble: `\makeatletter \patchcmd{\@maketitle}{\null}{}{}{} \makeatother`.