# Space size before a title in the Article class

Tags: spacing, titles, titling

What is the space size before a title in the Article class?

I want to use `\droptitle` from `titling` to place the title immediately after the top margin and I need the value to drop. By immediately I mean the same vertical position as one would get by beginning the document with plain text.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided a specific example of how you intend to use `\droptitle`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(code adapted from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/452985/5001) to the query [how does '\maketitle' work?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/452971/5001))

I will being by assuming that you do not specify the option `titlepage` while using the `article` document class. (Do let me know if this assumption is invalid.) To get rid of the vertical space that's otherwise inserted by default before `\maketitle`, just run the following code in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter 
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{\null}{}{}{} 
\makeatother
```

---

A full MWE (minimum working example) and its output -- the framelines are inserted because the optional `showframe` package is loaded:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe} % draw frame lines around text block
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter 
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{\null}{}{}{} 
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\title{Hello World}
\author{Somebody}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```