# Which command can I use to access the title defined by \title{}

Tags: titles

From the existence of the command `\maketitle` I believe the title is kept somewhere. So how can I have access to it by a command (for example I want to use it somewhere else). Finding it could be hard because the source code of article isn’t open to public.

Comment: You need to include more details, including `documentclass`, packages etc, `\maketitle`'s definition is in the public domain within source code. In fact there are [questions on here that find and change `\maketitle` for the `article` class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/452985/273733) so I am not sure what your question is?

Comment: Just add `\newcommand{\thisdocumenttitle}{The real title goes here}` and do `\title{\thisdocumenttitle}` for typesetting it with `\maketitle`. You have `\thisdocumenttitle` available whenever you want.

Comment: Similar questions has been asked in the past. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2522173

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you're submitting a paper to some journal that doesn't disclose the code of the document class they'll use to eventually typeset the paper and just provides a generic template.

The problem you have is simple to solve.

```
\documentclass{generic-publisher-class}

%%% Whatever you need in the preamble
\usepackage{amsmath}
%[...]
%%%

%%% add this for remembering the title
\newcommand{\thisdocumenttitle}{What's the name of this paper?}

\begin{document}

\author{A. Uthor}
\title{\thisdocumenttitle}

\maketitle

This paper is entitled ``\thisdocumenttitle'' and is the 
sequel to another paper of mine~\cite{mypreviouspaper}.

\end{document}
```